# 'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect' Error How To Fix?

Tags: python, html, pygame

so I have this script here and I am getting this error  'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect' I am not sure how to fix this

```
error  'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
```

what this does is that it moves my player image into my square hitbox

```
    def draw(self):
        self.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        player_rect = rights.get_rect(center = self.rect.center) 
        player_rect.centerx += 0 # 10 is just an example
        player_rect.centery += 0 # 15 is just an example
```

and this is my player class where I stored the code down below

```
# my players class
class player:
   def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.height = height
       self.width = width
       self.color = color
       self.isJump = False
       self.JumpCount = 10
       self.fall = 0
       self.speed = 5
       self.standingleft =[pygame.image.load("s1.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s2.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s3.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s4.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s5.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s6.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s7.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s8.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s9.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s10.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s11.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s12.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s13.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s14.png"),
           pygame.image.load("s15.png")]

       self.standingright = [pygame.image.load("d1.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d2.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d3.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d4.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d5.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d6.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d7.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d8.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d9.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d10.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d11.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d12.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d13.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d14.png"),
               pygame.image.load("d15.png")]


       self.rights = [pygame.image.load("L1.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L2.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L3.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L4.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L5.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L6.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L7.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L8.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L9.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L10.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L11.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L12.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L13.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L14.png"),
       pygame.image.load("L15.png")]


       self.lefts = [pygame.image.load("e1.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e2.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e3.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e4.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e5.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e6.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e7.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e8.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e9.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e10.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e11.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e12.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e13.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e14.png"),
       pygame.image.load("e15.png")]

       self.left_index = 0
       self.right_index = 0
       self.stand_index = 0
       self.anim_index = 0
       self.direction = "left"
       self.direction = "right"
       self.direction = "standright"
       self.rights = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()-400,image.get_height()-400)) for image in self.rights]
       self.lefts = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()-10,image.get_height()-10)) for image in self.lefts]
       self.standingright = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()-10,image.get_height()-10)) for image in self.standingright]
       self.standingleft = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()-10,image.get_height()-10)) for image in self.standingleft]

       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
   def draw(self):
       self.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
       player_rect = rights.get_rect(center = self.rect.center) 
       player_rect.centerx += 0 # 10 is just an example
       player_rect.centery += 0 # 15 is just an example
       window.blit(heart, player_rect)
       if self.direction == "right":
           window.blit(self.right[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
           self.anim_index += 1
           if self.anim_index == len(self.right):
               self.anim_index = 0
```

player classplayer classplayer classplayer classplayer classplayer classplayer class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the images are scaled to the same size by

> ```py
> pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()-400,image.get_height()-400))
> ```

Hence you can get the size from one representative surface object. Use the 1st surface in the list to get the size (`rights[0]`):

<s>`player_rect = rights.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)`</s>

```py
player_rect = right[0].get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not indicate which line the error was on, but I can guess it is this line.

```
player_rect = rights.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```

The error is relatively explanatory. "'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect'". says that tried to call get_rect() on a list, not a object like a surface that has a get_rect().

`rights` a list of images/surfaces and you are calling get_rect() on that list rather that on one of the things in the list.